# Add time to "yesterday" questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, timestamps

I'm always bugged by the inconsistency of this:

[Old Question/Answer http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/2975/sospecificdatetime.png](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/2975/sospecificdatetime.png)
[Yesterday http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8515/soyesterday.png](http://img340.imageshack.us/img340/8515/soyesterday.png)

I don't mind the "3 hours ago" thing so much for same-day questions, but it doesn't make much sense to me that I can see the specific time of day for *old* questions/answers but not for entries submitted *yesterday*.  Wouldn't most people be much more likely to care about the time of day for *newer* questions?  And it looks like there's more than enough room in there to add the `at hh:mm` text.

Call it nit-picking if you like, but I frequently find myself looking at the time stamps when I see two answers on a question that are almost the same, and want to vote up the one that *doesn't* plagiarize.  Anyway, I think the UI consistency argument alone justifies the request.

...Right?

Comment: Jeff means "status-dontcare".

Comment: That does seem to be the message, doesn't it?  Lol, of *course* it's "by design", it's the *design* that's being questioned here!  Almost reminds me of "works as coded."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this suggestion is declined, or until it is implemented, you could always accomplish this with a Greasemonkey script. I knew timestamps were recorded in UTC, but I didn't realize they were always displayed in UTC.

```
<span title="2010-03-15 18:40:23Z" class="relativetime">Mar 15 at 18:40</span>
```

At any rate, you can uncomment the one line in there to convert from UTC to your local time. That, though, may produce incorrect results for timestamps close to midnight.

```
var $ = (typeof unsafeWindow !== "undefined") ? unsafeWindow.$ : window.$;
function parseDate(s)
{
    var d = new Date(s.replace("Z", "").replace(/-/g, "/"));
    //d.setTime(d.getTime() - d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    return d.getHours().toString() + ":" + (d.getMinutes()+100).toString().substring(1);
}

$("span.relativetime").each(function ()
{
    if(this.innerHTML == "yesterday")
        this.innerHTML = "yesterday at " + parseDate(this.title);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If you keep your cursor hovering over the 'yesterday' for a few seconds, the exact timestamp will appear as a tooltip.

[image]

Comment: Interesting... it works, but it's completely non-discoverable (I've been using this site for several months and never realized that), and it's pretty awkward when trying to do comparisons. Thank you for the tip though.

Comment: @Aaron that's why I normally browse the site with answers sorted oldest first rather than by votes.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I'm curious why you care about the relative post time of answers? They should not matter at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When voting for an answer, I want to know the order. Sometimes a later answer isn't as deserving at it seems when taken in context with answers that came before.

Comment: @joel Hmm ideally we would analyse posts in their own right but ok