# Time is not shown for flags submitted yesterday

Tags: feature-request, flags, timestamps

There is a bit of a discrepancy when showing when a flag was submitted. A flag submitted yesterday does not show at what time it was submitted, it just states "yesterday".

Other, older, flags show the time, as well as the date.

> [image: No time stamp on yesterday's flag]

Not sure if this discrepancy is due to the "Pending" status.

It would be nice if the time is shown.

Why? Because I was wondering whether I should *reflag* my question for migration (in case it had fallen down a hole, or been forgotten about), and wanted to know how much time had passed. I thought that I had actually submitted the flag two days prior, and comparing its response time to those of my previous flags, it seemed as if the pending flag was taking its time in being "seen to". However, I was unable to determine exactly how long the delay was, as the time is not shown. Minor quibble, maybe.

---

With respect to this question being a possible duplicate, yes, agreed it is the *same* issue, relating to the timestamp mechanism, although those two questions ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210290/why-are-time-stamps-missing-from-recent-questions) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44309/add-time-to-yesterday-questions-answers)), relate only to questions/answers and make no  explicit mention of the issue occurring with flags as well.

However, looking through the answers to the other question(s), I have just discovered that [*hovering*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210290/why-are-time-stamps-missing-from-recent-questions#answer-210291) provides the time stamp that I was looking for:

> [image: Hovering over "yesterday" provides timestamp]

Comment: Any time information can be hovered over for exact UTC time code.

Comment: You really, really need to not re-flag stuff. Mods are normal people... they may be trying to decide whether your suggestion is good or not. All unhandled flags light up an alert... reflagging is just annoying.

Comment: @Catija - Thanks for answering my second unasked question... :-) I thought that it would be most annoying to reflag, that is why I held off. The question _in question_, or rather the bug that I raised on Russian SO, has actually been fixed due to my raising of the issue... so it should fit the criteria of a good suggestion.

Comment: @Catija - WRT the duplicate, yes, agreed it is the same issue, relating to the timestamp mechanism, although those two questions ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210290/why-are-time-stamps-missing-from-recent-questions) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44309/add-time-to-yesterday-questions-answers)), relate only to questions/answers and make no  explicit mention of the issue occurring with flags as well.

Comment: @Catija - Thanks for pointing out the other question(s) though, as I have just discovered that [_hovering_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210290/why-are-time-stamps-missing-from-recent-questions#answer-210291) provides the time stamp that I was looking for.

Comment: That's what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @Catija - ah... so you did. sorry.